# Добавление категорий и подкатегорий

Tags: php, laravel, opencart

Проблема: Не знаю как правильно при переборе добавлять категории, а точней как правильно передавать `$parent_id` С первым уровнем проблем нет, но потом я должен передать id прошлого элемента. Думал использовать рекурсию, но попытки тоже с ними уперся в тупик.

Есть массив категорий с базы данных `$categories`

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:1 [▼
    59 => array:3 [▼
      "parent_id" => 0
      "category_id" => 59
      "name" => "Home & lifestyle"
    ]
  ]
  59 => array:1 [▼
    60 => array:3 [▼
      "parent_id" => 59
      "category_id" => 60
      "name" => "Tableware"
    ]
  ]
  60 => array:1 [▼
    61 => array:3 [▼
      "parent_id" => 60
      "category_id" => 61
      "name" => "Plates"
    ]
  ]
]
```

Есть массив данных в таком виде. `$array` Разделяю вложенность символом `>`

```
array:298 [▼
  0 => "Home & lifestyle>Tableware>Plates"
  1 => "Woman>Clothing>Dresses"
  2 => "Girl>Clothing>Dresses"
  3 => "Girl>Clothing>Skirts"
  4 => "Woman>Clothing>Pants"
  5 => "Unisex>Accessories>Lifestyle"
  6 => "Unisex>Accessories>Hi-tech"
  10 => "Woman>Clothing>T-shirt"
```

Код

```
$categories = Category::getAllCategories($language_id);
$history = [
    'total' => 0,
    'update' => 0,
    'insert' => 0
];

foreach ($array as $line){
    $items = explode('>', $line);
    $parent_id = 0;
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $category_id = Category::findCategoryIdByName($item, $parent_id, $language_id);

        if($category_id){
            $history['total'] += 1;
            $history['update'] += 1;
        }else{
            $history['insert'] += 1;
            $history['total'] += 1;
        }

    }

}
```